# Can I change the shebang path to bash in sbt-native-packager?

Tags: freebsd, sbt-native-packager

I'm using the `stage` command of sbt-native-packager to generate a start script for my application.  The start-script template uses

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to find `bash`, but I'm on FreeBSD, thus my `bash` is in `/usr/local/bin/bash`.  Is there a workaround for this that is any more convenient than invoking `bash` with the script filename as its argument, or editing the script each time it's regenerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to override template. Just put copy of original template with appropriate changes in src/templates. But notice that this feature available only in 0.7.0-M1.

Comment: I notice that `#!/bin/bash` is now `#!/bin/env bash`.  I don't know the reason for the change, but it solved the problem for me so thanks!  At least until a malicious hacker installs a trojan horse named `bash` in my path :)